# C# How to access a value in an array and compare it's value

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am trying to build a Basic Mars Rover program to control the movements of a Mars Rover.  The grid area is 100m x 100m. The rover starts by facing south and can turn in the directions of left and right moving in metres taking a maximum of 5 commands at any time. The rover starts at grid position 1 and after each set of commands reports back its current position and direction it is facing.

e.g

1. 50m
2. Left
3. 23m
4. Left
5. 4m

The above set of commands would cause the rover to report back position 4624/North.

At this moment I am wanting to pass an array into a method to check the rows and columns against the users moves to make sure they are within the grid boundary.

How do I access the value within the array?

This is what I have currently, but I get an Error:

> invalid expression term 'int' at int [rows, columns] = grid;

```
public bool gridBoundary(int[,] grid, int choice)
{
    int rows = 0;
    int columns = 0;


    int [rows, columns] = grid;


    if (choice > rows || choice > columns) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: See this MSDN tutorial to straighten out your syntax errors: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx. You can also consider using a `List<List<int>>` if you want to be able to use `.Length` on specific dimensions.

Comment: As you wrote it right now, that would translate into English as "create an integer variable named '[rows, columns]', and set its value to be the whole array". '[rows, columns]' isn't a valid variable name, and you can't set an int equal to an array. It is also unclear what the values of rows and columns are supposed to be? The size of the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used **grid.length** and **>= 0** to determine if the move was within the grid's boundaries. If Rover was within boundary I set the new facing position depending on which way the rover was originally facing and direction it was using. This was all placed inside a **For Loop** to produce 5 moves.

```
         /*
         * startingDirection North 1, East 2, South 3, West 4
         * userDirection Left 1, Right 2, None 3
         *
         */ Works out the current position of the Rover

    public void currentLocation(int[,] grid, int direction,int row, int column, int move )
    {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner();
        Messgae message = new Messgae();

        for (int i = 0; i <=5; i++)
        {
            switch (direction)
            {
                case 1:
                    if (row - move >= 0 ) 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n Direction facing North, grid position " + grid.GetValue(row - move, column) + "\n");
                        row = row - move;
                        direction = currentDirection(scanner.getDirection(), 1);
                        move = scanner.getMove();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message.endMessage();
                        i = 5;
                        break;
                    }

                case 2:
                    if(column + move <= grid.Length) 
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n Direction facing East, grid position " + grid.GetValue(row, column + move) + "\n");
                        direction = currentDirection(scanner.getDirection(), 2);
                        column = column + move;
                        move = scanner.getMove();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message.endMessage();
                        i = 5;
                        break;
                    }

                case 3:
                    if(row + move <= grid.Length)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n Direction facing South, grid position " + grid.GetValue(row + move, column) + "\n");
                        direction = currentDirection(scanner.getDirection(), 3);
                        row = row + move;
                        move = scanner.getMove();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message.endMessage();
                        i = 5;
                        break;
                    }

                case 4:
                    if (column - move >= 0)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\n Direction facing West, grid position " + grid.GetValue(row, column - move) + "\n");
                        direction = currentDirection(scanner.getDirection(), 4);
                        column = column - move;
                        move = scanner.getMove();
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        message.endMessage();
                        i = 5;
                        break;
                    }

                default:
                    break;

            }// End switch
        }// End for loop
    }// End currentLocation()
```

Comment: Consider rewriting using proper functional decomposition, this is really hard to read and will be difficult to maintain.

Comment: Yes I agree, it was just a simple project that I just needed to get working. Looking at in now I would make a few changes, thanks for the advice

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get length of the dimensions, use [`Array.GetLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlength.aspx) method:

```
int rows = grid.GetLength(0);
int columns = grid.GetLength(1);
```